# Code of Conduct banner fails to 'Be Nice' (enough) for small screens

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notification-bar, code-of-conduct

When viewing Meta Stack Exchange (with the responsive design) on Safari on iOS (or any browser with a small width), the text in the Code of Conduct banner overlaps with the site icon. The link (in blue) even disappears in the blue background.

[image]

Comment: Well, it works exactly as it is programmed, that's for sure...

Comment: This was updated quite a bit ago, sorry it took so long to mark this as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The announcement banner was created prior to the rollout of responsive pages. We're working on fixing it.